# How to make code work - USACO Training First Task

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with the first problem on the USACO Training Page.

The task is asking for two strings from a text.in file, converting the strings into a number that is the product of the letters (where a=1, b=2, z=26), then seeing if the remainders of the numbers/47 are equal to each other (if they are, print "GO", if not, print "STAY").

It works great on my computer, but when I send it in, it displays:

```
> Run 1: Execution error: Your program exited with exit status `1'. 

    ------ Data for Run 1 [length=14 bytes] ------
    COMETQ 
    HVNGAT 
    ----------------------------

      Your program printed data to stderr.  Here is the data:
      -------------------
      Exception_in_thread_"main"_java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:_ride
      Caused_by:_java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:_ride
        at_java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at_java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native_Method)
        at_java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at_java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at_sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at_java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at_java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
      Could_not_find_the_main_class:_ride.__Program_will_exit.
      -------------------
```

Now this is my code:

```
/*
  ID:swagato1
  LANG:JAVA
  PROG:ride 
*/
import java.io.*;
class Ride{
    public void calculate() throws IOException{
       BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
       PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));
       String c=in.readLine();
       String g=in.readLine();
    int a=1,b=1;
    for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++)
        a*=((int)c.charAt(i))-64;
    for(int i=0;i<g.length();i++)
        b*=((int)g.charAt(i))-64;
    if ((a%47)==(b%47))
        out.println("GO");
    else
        out.println("STAY");
    out.close();
    System.exit(0);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{new Ride().calculate();}
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}        
}
```

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.  This is about a runtime error, not efficiency.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more careful

Comment: @Mark Peters Sorry I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class `public`:

```
public class Ride{

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class name must be exactly like task name. In this case it should be `ride` not `Ride`. Making class `public` does not help.